# What's next after Project Management?

Tags: career

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Functional Managers or Project Managers Better Candidates for Executive-Level Positions?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/)

I've been working as a software developer for a year now. I'm seriously considering PM as a career ahead. I actually have 2 questions here.

After being a PM for 4-5 years, what's next?

Also, is it possible to reach senior executive/senior management positions after doing Project management for 12-15 years (or is it possible for a PM to become a senior executive at all)?

Comment: See also http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/ to address whether PM can become an exec.

Comment: The "Possible Duplicate" link is broken.

Comment: Hi @PeterK., I'll mark your flag as helpful, but keep in mind that you can suggest an edit that removes, or fixes, the broken link. I went ahead and made the update. Duplicate posts are sometimes helpful as a means of directing more traffic to the canonical post, so fixing the link is definitely a positive step forward. Thank you! :)

Comment: @jmort253: Thanks!  I wasn't sure where the link was supposed to go... so I didn't suggest the edit. :-)